# How to use a vector<unsigned> v, as the key to search a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I have a:

```
vector<unsigned> v;
```

How can I use the numbers/values in the vector as a Key to search a

```
map <unsigned, unsigned>& mp
```

the map is formed by

```
map.insert(pair<unsigned, unsigned>(v, sthelse))
```

from another data sets.

Comment: FYI, instead of std::pair<type, type>(var, var) you can do std::make_pair(var, var).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `vector<unsigned>` as a key to search a `map<unsigned, unsigned>`. As the first template parameter to `map<>` indicates, the type of the key is `unsigned`, not `vector<unsigned>`.

You *can* use the **members** of the vector as keys to search the map, like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
  auto it = mp.find(v[i]);
  if(it != mp.end()) {
    std::cout << "Look, Martha, we caught one! " << it->second << "\n";  
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423753/how-to-use-a-vectorunsigned-v-as-the-key-to-search-a-mapThanks a lot!